# Change the CSS of a DIV in an iFrame from Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I just started to go further in my web development skills in my job and stucked with a little problem.

I have an iFrame (iframe.html), and in this iframe is a div styled as a green square.
I want to change the color of the Div outside the iframe with a button in my Parent (index.html) with an onClick Function.

I tried a few things, like calling a normal Function (document.getElementById and so on). But nothing really worked.
So I thought, that jquery might have some solutions and I'm stucked now in this code, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

PS: this is not a cross-origin case. i got both html files in the same Directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

        <title>buttonframetest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Clickit() {
                 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('iframe').contents().find('background-color').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
            });
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="iframe.html" width="500px;" height="500px">
        <p>iFrame nicht darstellbar in deinem Browser</p>
        </iframe>
        <br>
        <button type='button' onClick="Clickit();">Klick</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="redy">CHANGE</button>
        <br>
        <div class="ChangeColor"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add your remaining code here or in fiddle.

Comment: @frnt just edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this,

Update your jQuery CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
function clck(){
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('iframe').css({
        'background' : '#fff'
        });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the DOM iframe object's `contentDocument` property:

```
document.frames[0].contentDocument.getElementById('id here').style['background-color']=whatever;
```

Or, alternatively, with `window.postMessage`:

```
// this is in parent
document.frames[0].postMessage('red', '*');

// this is in frame
window.onmessage = function(x) {
    if (x.origin == 'http://www.example.com') document.getElementById('id here').style['background-color'] = x.data;
}
```